# Fields set by JQuery not "seen" by Form

Tags: jquery, webforms

I am working on forms rendered and displayed in a web portal by ADX Studio. I am using JQuery to add scripting to the forms, and I need to set some fields to read-only based on a selection from an Option Set. I tried both:

```
$("#<field name>").prop('disabled', true );
and
$("#<field name>").attr('readonly', true);
```

But when I do that, the form cannot "see" the values in the read-only fields that are drop-downs, the values are cleared and I get a field validation error.

So 2 questions, is there a way to disabled the fields without losing the values, and is there a way to hide just the "arrow" on the drop-down so the drop-down doesn't function?

Thanks.

John.

Comment: You could use hidden fields to store information

Comment: A validator should quite rightly not attempt to validate disabled fields. Why? Two reasons - (1) if a disabled field fails validation, there's nothing the user can do about it without the field being enabled, so it might as well be enabled in the first place, (2) disabled fields are not submitted.